# Dynamic Import - Python - Call function not working

Tags: python, reflection

I am having some trouble with dynamically importing Classes and attempting to run functions in said classes. This is my problem, specifically.

I have a python script `dyn_imports.py` in a director called `dynamic_imports`. Inside this folder is a subdir called `scripts`. In this scripts directory there is an `__init__.py` and a python class called `AbhayScript.py`. In the class `AbhayScript`, there is a function called `say_hello()`

My objective is: From `dyn_imports.py`, I would like to be able to import `scripts.AbhayScript` and call the function `say_hello()` in `AbhayScript`

So far, I have attempted a variety of options including `__import__`, `importlib.import_module` and `pydoc.locate`. All of these options give me access to the `module` AbhayScript but when I try a `getattrs()` or try to call the object, I get an error stating that its not callable or has no attribute.

**dyn_imports.py - One of my experiments**

```
myclass = 'scripts.AbhayScript'

import importlib
mymod = importlib.import_module(myclass)
mod,newclass = myclass.rsplit('.',1)
ncls = getattr(mod,newclass) #throws an AttributeError that 'str' object has no attribute
```

**AbhayScript.py code**

```
class AbhayScript(object):

    def say_hello(self):
        print 'Hello Abhay Bhargav'
```

The directory structure is as follows

[image: Directory Structure of Project]

The **init**.py in the scripts folder is empty.

**I have attempted nearly all the solutions in Stackoverflow, but I am a little flummoxed by this one. What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize what I was doing wrong. I was importing the module and not referencing the class in the `getattr` function. I made the class declaration explicit in the `__import__` function and in the `getattr` function and I was subsequently able to gain access to the functions in the class

**Here's the code in dyn_imports.py**

```
myclass = 'scripts.AbhayScript'

mod = __import__(myclass, fromlist = ['AbhayScript']) #class explicit
klass = getattr(mod, 'AbhayScript') #explicit class
klass().say_hello() #calls the function as desired
```